# ionic app connects to the server in simulator successfully, however it fails as an apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, connection, runtime-error, apk

I made an app in ionic that loads information from a server. It works perfectly without a problem in the browser. Also if I use IONIC DEVAPP on my device it works perfectly fine. However if i make an APK, the app fails on the exact same device. I viewed the result of the data received from the server and I got the following:

[image: ErrorMessage]

I have no idea what the problem is since the reply does give me a clue what this information is for or what should i do about it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

yours sincerely.

Comment: check console using chrome://inspect

Comment: I am getting this error on the device not on chrome.

Comment: Yes but you also check error log of mobile using chrome://inspect

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a CORS policy issue. At least I have something to work with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help you.!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paresh Gami  to point me to the device log. It was a CORS policy issue. I just updates the server with the new origin listed in the log and the app works fine.